# Escrow.sol: The called function should be payable if you send value and the value you send should be less than your current balance

Tags: solidity, remix, erc-20, escrow

I'm trying to do `Escrow.sol` with ERC20 token. When I deploy the Escrow.sol on Remix and wanna deposit 10 tokens, it appears `The called function should be payable if you send value and the value you send should be less than your current balance.` So did the function of withdraw.

How can I fix it?

the following is my **erc20.sol**

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-3.0
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

import "https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol";

contract MyToken is ERC20 {
    constructor() ERC20("GINWEI", "GW") public payable {
        _mint(msg.sender, 1000);
    }
}
```

and the following is **escrow.sol**

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-3.0
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

import "./erc20.sol";

contract MyEscrow {

    mapping(address => mapping(address => uint256)) public _deposits;
    address payable payee = payable(msg.sender);
    MyToken token;

    function deposit(uint256 amount) public payable {
        token.approve(address(this), amount);
        token.transfer(address(this), amount);
        _deposits[payee][address(token)] += amount;
    }

    function depositsOf() public view returns (uint256) {
        return _deposits[payee][address(token)];
    }

    function withdraw(uint256 payment) public payable {
        _deposits[payee][address(token)] -= payment;
        payee.transfer(payment);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show how are you calling the functions from your test?

Answer (score 1):

Your `MyEscrow` smart contract have any issues, let me explain them:

- When you declare this statement `MyToken token;` like storage variable, you must instantiate it with the erc20's smart contact address for use ERC20 methods. An example how to fix this issue:

  `MyToken token = MyToken([addressERC20SmartContract]);`
- `token.approve(address(this), amount);` this statement is wrong because you're approving your MyEscrow smart contract to transfer an token quantity that it doesn't have. To solve it, a user must call `approve()` from your ERC20 smart contract in this case `MyToken` smart contract. When call `approve`, he must pass these values inside these paramters:

  - spender: `MyEscrow` smart contract address;
  - amount: how many token `MyEscrow` can transfer from your wallet.
- Finally, in `withdraw` function for transfer an ERC20 from smart contract to user wallet you can use `transfer()` ERC20 method and pass inside it the `msg.sender` and the value to withdraw.

I have corrected your `MyEscrow` smart contract in this way:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-3.0
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

import "./erc20.sol";

contract MyEscrow {

    mapping(address => mapping(address => uint256)) public _deposits;
    address payable payee = payable(msg.sender);
    MyToken token;

    constructor(address _myToken) {
        token = MyToken(_myToken); 
    }

    function deposit(uint256 amount) public payable {
        token.transferFrom(msg.sender, address(this), amount);
        _deposits[payee][address(token)] += amount;
    }

    function depositsOf() public view returns (uint256) {
        return _deposits[payee][address(token)];
    }

    function withdraw(uint256 payment) public payable {
        _deposits[payee][address(token)] -= payment;
        token.transfer(msg.sender, payment);
    }
}
```

Comment: thx for ur explaination! But when i tried to deposit by the modified escrow.sol, it appears `Reason provided by the contract: "ERC20: insufficient allowance"`

Answer (score 0):

After several trying, I combined the sol from @Kerry99 and my original code, and it works perfectly!

the func `approve()` has been overriden.

```
contract MyEscrow {

    mapping(address => mapping(address => uint256)) public _deposits;
    address payable payee = payable(msg.sender);
    address tokenaddress = 0x...;
    MyToken token = MyToken(tokenaddress);

    function deposit(uint256 amount) public payable {
        token.approve(msg.sender, address(this), amount);
        token.transferFrom(msg.sender, address(this), amount);
        _deposits[payee][tokenaddress] += amount;
    }

    function depositsOf() public view returns (uint256) {
        return _deposits[payee][tokenaddress];
    }

    function withdraw(uint256 payment) public payable {
        _deposits[payee][tokenaddress] -= payment;
        token.transfer(msg.sender, payment);
    }
}
```